# C++ function only casting bytes returns address to stack variable

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm writing a function which simply casts bytes from an existing memory address (see code below).

However, unfortunately it's implying i'm creating a stack variable and returning a reference to that:

```
error: reference to local variable 'bytes' returned [-Werror=return-local-addr]
    5 |     return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(bytes);
```

Why is this? I didn't think the cast was creating a new object/memory address.

How should it be implemented?

```
template<class T>
const T& getT(const char* bytes)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(bytes);
}

int main()
{
    int p = getT<int>("");
}
```

Comment: Is the mistake obvious if you write it as `return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(*&bytes);`?

Comment: The function parameter (`const char* bytes`) is a stack-based variable, and you are returning a reference to that.  `bytes` will go out of scope when `getT` returns, leaving that reference dangling.

Comment: @mezamorphic that's now what you're doing. From what I can see you want to `return *reinterpret_cast<T const*>(bytes);`  (yuck, btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig Reason I'm puzzled is references and pointers are the same thing, so is it not possible to write it in terms of references?

Comment: There's part of the problem. References and pointers are NOT the same thing. For one thing a reference has to refer to a valid instance of an object and a pointer doesn't.

Comment: What you are trying to do is undefined behavior anyway. You cannot reinterpret a pointer to some random type and dereference it, that is simply not allowed by C++.

Comment: I'm interested in what is really happening at `reinterpret_cast<const T&>(bytes);`. I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's turning the address contained by `bytes` into a reference to an `int`, not type-punning a char array into an `int`.

Comment: [Godbolt suggests I'm right.](https://godbolt.org/z/Gvnc38Wec)

Comment: @user4581301 Not the address _contained_ in `bytes`.  It returns a reference to the variable `bytes` itself, coerced to `int&`.  Yuk.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error is correct.  You are indeed returning a reference to a local variable, so the reference will be left dangling when `getT()` exits.

The `bytes` parameter is local to `getT()`.  You are returning a reference to `bytes` itself, not a reference to what `bytes` is pointing at.  If you want that, you need to *dereference* `bytes` first:

```cpp
template<class T>
const T& getT(const char* bytes)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(*bytes);
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
template<class T>
const T& getT(const char* bytes)
{
    return *(reinterpret_cast<const T*>(bytes));
}
```

Just note that you are passing `""` to `getT<int>()`, where `""` is a `const char[1]` (holding just a null terminator), and `sizeof(int)` is more than 1 byte, so you are going to be invoking *undefined behavior* by reading past the end of the `char[]` into surrounding memory.  The following code would exhibit expected and well-defined behavior, though:

```cpp
int main()
{
    char buf[sizeof(int)];
    int value = 12345;
    memcpy(&buf, &value, sizeof(value));
    int p = getT<int>(buf);
    cout << p;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/5BdTCs)